# Set an image next to filter bar in .jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to set an image on the specific column but when I set it using `formatter`, I am not getting expected result. Image is overriding data.

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  $("#myDialogBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  
  $("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
    { name: "BatchID", label: "Batch ID", align: "center"}, 
    { name: "Status",  label: "Status", align: "center", formatter: "select", 
       formatoptions: { value: "CAN:Canceled; COM:Completed; PEN:Pending", defaultValue: "PEN" },
       stype: "select", searchoptions: { value: ":Pending;CAN:Canceled; COM:Completed"} },
    { name: "StartRunDate", label: "Start Run Date", align: "center", sorttype:"date", 
      formatter: function () { return "<img src='http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif' alt='calendar' />"; },
      formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y" } },
    { name: "StartRunTime", label: "Start Run Time", align: "center", sorttype:"time", formatter: "time" },  
    { name: "EndRunDate", label: "End Run Date", align: "center",  editable:true, sorttype:"date" },
    { name: "EndRunTime", label: "End RunTime", align: "center",  editable:true, sorttype:"time" },
    { name: "Action",  label: "Action", align: "center", formatter: "showlink"}, 
    { name: "JobID",  label: "Job ID", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "JobName",  label: "Job Name", align: "center"}, 
    { name: "ConceptName", label: "Concept Name", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "StartDate", label: "Start Date", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "EndDate", label: "End Date", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "Frequency", label: "Frequency", align: "center",
      formatter: "select",
      formatoptions: { value: "ALL:All; DAI:Daily; WEK:Weekly", defaultValue: "ALL" },
      stype: "select",
      searchoptions: { value: ":All; DAI:Daily; WEK:Weekly" } },
    { name: "QueryLink", label: "Query Link", align: "center",
      formatter: function() { return '<button class="popup-trigger">Pop Up</button>' } },
    { name: "Submitter", label: "Submitter", align: "center"}
    ],
    data: [
    { BatchID: "1", Status: "Pending", StartRunDate: "7/12/2017", StartRunTime:"12:00", EndRunDate: "7/12/2017",
      EndRunTime:"1:00", Action: "Cancel Delivery", JobID: "123", JobName: "Test", ConceptName: "CPK",    StartDate: "7/12/2017", EndDate: "7/12/2017", Frequency: "All", QueryLink: "Link", Submitter: "John Doe"  
    }],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "invdate",
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: ".jqGrid Test"
  }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autoSearch: true}).on('click', '.popup-trigger', function() {
    $("#myDialogBox").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.13.6/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="myDialogBox" title="Basic dialog"></div>
```

Expected result: Want calendar icon next to `x`.

[image]

What am I missing here? Is there any `.jqGrid` restriction here?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. The current code format the input data `"7/12/2017"` as the icon. If you type the string `7/12/2017` in the filter toolbar of the column `StartRunDate` you'll get the data filtered by the value: one row. If you type any other value as `7/12/2017` (for example `8/12/2017`) in the filter toolbar and press Enter then no rows will be displayed.

Comment: @Oleg sorry for the confusion. I want `calendar` icon next to `x` and `7/12/2017` where the icon is. Searching is fine. I am having an issue with setting an icon next to filter bar. What I am doing right now replaces `7/12/2017` with an image which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I correctly understand what you want. Below you can find modification of your code with some changes in `colModel` of `StartRunDate` and small additional CSS rule

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  $("#myDialogBox").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  
  $("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
    { name: "BatchID", label: "Batch ID", align: "center"}, 
    { name: "Status",  label: "Status", align: "center", formatter: "select", 
       formatoptions: { value: "CAN:Canceled; COM:Completed; PEN:Pending", defaultValue: "PEN" },
       stype: "select", searchoptions: { value: ":Pending;CAN:Canceled; COM:Completed"} },
    { name: "StartRunDate", label: "Start Run Date", align: "center", sorttype:"date", 
      formatter: function (cellval, opions, rawdata, act) {
          return $.fn.fmatter.call(this, "date", cellval, opions, rawdata, act) +
"&nbsp;<img src='https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif' alt='calendar' style='display:inline-block;vertical-align: middle;' />"; },
      formatoptions: { srcformat: "m/d/Y" },
      searchoptions: {
          sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"],
          attr: {
              placeholder: "m/d/yyyy",
              style: "width: 110px; display: inline-block;"
          },
          dataInit: function (elem, options) {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage: "https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
                });
            }
      } },
    { name: "StartRunTime", label: "Start Run Time", align: "center", sorttype:"time", formatter: "time" },  
    { name: "EndRunDate", label: "End Run Date", align: "center",  editable:true, sorttype:"date" },
    { name: "EndRunTime", label: "End RunTime", align: "center",  editable:true, sorttype:"time" },
    { name: "Action",  label: "Action", align: "center", formatter: "showlink"}, 
    { name: "JobID",  label: "Job ID", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "JobName",  label: "Job Name", align: "center"}, 
    { name: "ConceptName", label: "Concept Name", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "StartDate", label: "Start Date", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "EndDate", label: "End Date", align: "center" }, 
    { name: "Frequency", label: "Frequency", align: "center",
      formatter: "select",
      formatoptions: { value: "ALL:All; DAI:Daily; WEK:Weekly", defaultValue: "ALL" },
      stype: "select",
      searchoptions: { value: ":All; DAI:Daily; WEK:Weekly" } },
    { name: "QueryLink", label: "Query Link", align: "center",
      formatter: function() { return '<button class="popup-trigger">Pop Up</button>' } },
    { name: "Submitter", label: "Submitter", align: "center"}
    ],
    data: [
    { BatchID: "1", Status: "Pending", StartRunDate: "7/12/2017", StartRunTime:"12:00", EndRunDate: "7/12/2017",
      EndRunTime:"1:00", Action: "Cancel Delivery", JobID: "123", JobName: "Test", ConceptName: "CPK",    StartDate: "7/12/2017", EndDate: "7/12/2017", Frequency: "All", QueryLink: "Link", Submitter: "John Doe"  
    }],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    rownumbers: true,
    sortname: "invdate",
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: ".jqGrid Test"
  }).jqGrid('filterToolbar', {autoSearch: true}).on('click', '.popup-trigger', function() {
    $("#myDialogBox").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-search-input img.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="myDialogBox" title="Basic dialog"></div>
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I modified your code a little bit to get the desired result. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/gunjan_prmr/153xxhL9/) is what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion.